# Does cached-resources plugin work with Grails 1.3.7

Tags: jquery, performance, caching, grails

Maybe a dumb question...? (I think only Grails 1.2.* is supported?)

Im trying to use cached-resources with grails 1.3.7 following the simple example for the jquery plugin

E.g.

JqueryResources.groovy

```
modules = {
'jquery' {
    resource url:[plugin:'jquery',dir:'js/jquery', file:'jquery-1.4.4-min.js'], disposition:'head'
}
```

}

I am getting the following exception

```
2011-05-13 17:35:11,944 [main] ERROR resource.ResourceService  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-1.4.4.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4-min.js
2011-05-13 17:35:11,991 [main] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [resources:1.0-RC2]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot locate resource [/plugins/jquery-1.4.4.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4-min.js]
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot locate resource [/plugins/jquery-1.4.4.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4-min.js]
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
```

Maybe im defining the path to the resource incorrectly?

E.g. Path to jquery. ../web-app/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4-min.js

Comment: You'd be better off using something more current like http://www.grails.org/plugin/ui-performance which is also going to be incorporated in the grails core for 1.4.